# WGet fails to download with an IPv6 address

Tags: wget, ipv6, download, ip-address, ipv4

When I try to download something with WGet, usually it fails if the domain name is translated to an IPv6 address.

That happens more often when there's a link redirection.

For example:

```
$ wget --inet6-only https://raw.githubusercontent.com/walkxcode/Dashboard-Icons/main/png/ebay.png
--2022-11-13 10:27:05--  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/walkxcode/Dashboard-Icons/main/png/ebay.png
Resolving raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)... 2606:50c0:8001::154, 2606:50c0:8000::154, 2606:50c0:8003::154, ...
Connecting to raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)|2606:50c0:8001::154|:443...
```

---

```
$ wget --inet6-only https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/9/x86_64/stable/Packages/docker-ce-20.10.21-3.el9.x86_64.rpm
--2022-11-13 10:32:52--  https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/9/x86_64/stable/Packages/docker-ce-20.10.21-3.el9.x86_64.rpm
Resolving download.docker.com (download.docker.com)... 2600:9000:21ed:e000:3:db06:4200:93a1, 2600:9000:21ed:2e00:3:db06:4200:93a1, 2600:9000:21ed:7000:3:db06:4200:93a1, ...
Connecting to download.docker.com (download.docker.com)|2600:9000:21ed:e000:3:db06:4200:93a1|:443...
```

In the first example, the `raw.githubusercontent.com` name is resolved to `2606:50c0:8001::154, 2606:50c0:8000::154, 2606:50c0:8003::154`. Then, WGget tries to connect to this IP and nothing else happens, just freezes. No download is made.
The same happens to the second example, `download.docker.com`.

When I force an IPv4 connection, it downloads the content successfully.

```
$ wget --inet4-only https://raw.githubusercontent.com/walkxcode/Dashboard-Icons/main/png/ebay.png
--2022-11-13 10:28:16--  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/walkxcode/Dashboard-Icons/main/png/ebay.png
Resolving raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)... 185.199.109.133, 185.199.108.133, 185.199.110.133, ...
Connecting to raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)|185.199.109.133|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 24872 (24K) [image/png]
Saving to: ‘ebay.png’

ebay.png                                  100%[==================================================================================>]  24.29K  --.-KB/s    in 0.005s

2022-11-13 10:28:16 (4.48 MB/s) - ‘ebay.png’ saved [24872/24872]
```

---

```
$ wget --inet4-only https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/9/x86_64/stable/Packages/docker-ce-20.10.21-3.el9.x86_64.rpm
--2022-11-13 10:34:35--  https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/9/x86_64/stable/Packages/docker-ce-20.10.21-3.el9.x86_64.rpm
Resolving download.docker.com (download.docker.com)... 52.84.83.27, 52.84.83.65, 52.84.83.79, ...
Connecting to download.docker.com (download.docker.com)|52.84.83.27|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 21654080 (21M) [binary/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘docker-ce-20.10.21-3.el9.x86_64.rpm’

docker-ce-20.10.21-3.el9.x86_64.rpm       100%[==================================================================================>]  20.65M  27.3MB/s    in 0.8s

2022-11-13 10:34:36 (27.3 MB/s) - ‘docker-ce-20.10.21-3.el9.x86_64.rpm’ saved [21654080/21654080]
```

Why is WGet failing with IPv6?

Comment: Do you have an ipv6 connection for your client?

Comment: Yes, @roaima, my host has a valid global IPv6 address.

Comment: What happens when you ping and traceroute to 2606:50c0:8001::154?

Comment: I cannot ping nor trace 2606:50c0:8001::154 IPv6 address. On the other hand, 185.199.109.133 does ping.